# Logic: Can you drop parentheses in a conjunction?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In propositional logic, $p \land (q \land r) = (p \land q) \land r$ , where $p, q$ and $r$ are propositions.

Does this mean $p \land (q \land r) = p \land q \land r$ ? If so, why?

Comment: Yes. You can drop parenthesis if you only work with $\lor$ or $\land$. Just because of the associativity you have shown above. This is because while evaluating the logical expression you can only compare terms pairwise, but this, as shown in your associativity statement, is independent of the parenthesing. Thus you can drop the overflow of notation without losing information.

Comment: It depends on what you meanexactly. If you're asking if the conjunction is associative, the answer is yes. If you're asking if $p\land q\land r$ is a well formed formula equivalent (in some sense) to, for instance, $p\land (q\land r)$ then the answer is probably no.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right: conjunction is associative. Thus, it doesn't matter where you put the parentheses. Hence, when you see "$p \land q \land r$", it means that you may insert the parentheses anywhere and you will get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend avoiding "p∧q∧r" and the like when talking in a proof-theoretic context.  In a proof-theoretic context a proof is a sequence of well-formed formulas (wffs).  I can tell which wff p∧(q∧r) stands for and I can tell which wff (p∧q)∧r stands for (neither of those strings are wffs).  But, I can't tell which wff p∧q∧r stands for.  It could mean (p∧(q∧r)) or ((p∧q)∧r) or it could mean both (p∧(q∧r)) and ((p∧q)∧r).  And thus, in a proof-theoretic context p∧q∧r is meaningless.

Answer (score -1):

Informally, one might say that if three things are true ($p \land q \land r$), then also one thing and two things — $p \land (q \land r)$ — and two things and one thing — $(p \land q) \land r$ — are true.

In a formal deductive system commonplace in symbolic logic, we want to be more formal. We usually deduce consequences from a *set* of premises. For example we deduce $p \land q$ from the set $\{p, q\}$. This is written:
$$\{p,q\} \vdash p \land q$$
where the braces are usually omitted, and $\vdash$ is voiced *proves*. Similarly:
$$p \land q \vdash p \qquad\qquad p\land q \vdash q$$
(where the premises thus are considered singleton sets) because this is simply throwing information away.

If we now allow chains of deduction, then, one easily obtains:
$$\begin{align*}\{p,q,r\} &\vdash p \land q& \{p \land q, r\} &\vdash (p \land q) \land r\\
\{p,q,r\}&\vdash q \land r&\{p, q \land r\}&\vdash p \land(q \land r)
\end{align*}$$
and from the rightmost conclusion the so-called *$\land$-elimination rules*  easily allow deriving $p, q$ and $r$ again. Thus either of the parenthesized expressions corresponds exactly to the truth of the three letters $p,q,r$. Thus we say they're *(provably) equivalent*:
$$p \land (q \land r) \dashv\vdash (p \land q) \land r$$

Thus we have demonstrated that the following definitions of $p \land q \land r$ are all equally sensible:

- As $p \land (q \land r)$;
- As $(p \land q) \land r$;
- By stating $p \land q \land r$ is true precisely when $p,q,r$ are all true.